# Php codeigniter Api call issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

I'm making API call for other developers to use, so my question might sound silly but i need the community help. So thanking in advance.

I finished an API call for a web service using this https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver. All api calls working perfectly when i test it using postman plugin for chrome.

I've forwarded my API call to an android developer and he was able to use GET methods by using direct URL. now he is asking me to provide direct URL to the POST, PUT and DELETE API call,  Which i do not know how to provide.

If for example, this is my API call to use the GET method, http://example.com/api/chemists/2 using the method chemists_GET. How do i get the direct URL to this PUT API call using this method chemists_PUT. like wise chemists_POST and chemists_DELETE method.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yoyu have ki9nd of answered it yourself... with the link you gave...

You're URL's to the endpoints will be as you have them... however you will need to implement the post functions etc as defined in https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#responses that page also described delete and put too...

Comment: Yes Brain i have implemented the Post function as well but need to know what could be the URL output that the developer is asking for. for example, http://example.com/api/chemist/post ???.

FYI the PUT, POST, DELETE working fine in POSTMAN

Comment: No need for it in the url... POST, GET and so on are the method calls i.e. they will make a cURL request using the GET, POST, DELETE verbs - similar to how what POSTMAN is doing, so if they are asking for something different it is their understanding of how to call a resful api that is at fault... you might need to create some dig out some example curl calls ... can even be command-line calls to prove it to them.

I.e.: curl -X GET|POST|DELETE http://example.com/api/chemists/2 (http://conqueringthecommandline.com/book/curl - has examples on how to do each command properly).